# Como "parar de escutar" uma Porta HTTP Server com NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

Quero verificar se o meu http server está executando, se está fechá-lo e abrir um novo.
O meu problema, é que a minha porta começa a escutar, mas eu quero fechá-la, porém pra fechar tenho que reiniciar o servidor...

```
if(server.isConnected){
   server.close();
}else{
   server.listen(PORTA, ()...);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

O código que você mostrou sempre vai iniciar o servidor, pois caso outro processo já esteja usando a porta a instância *server* não sabe dessa informação e essa condição é executada antes do *server* iniciar.

Para saber isso você pode checar no S.O. antes de executar o código, supondo que você queira verificar se a porta 8080 está em uso:

- Windows: `netstat -a -n -o | find "8080"`
- Linux/MacOS: `lsof -i :8080`

Caso os comandos retornem resultados, já existe outro processo utilizando a porta, você pode procurar o processo pelo número no gerenciandor de tarefas do S.O. e finalizar ou usar os comandos:

- Windows: `taskkill /PID NUMERO_PID /F`
- Linux/MacOS: `kill -9 NUMERO_PID`

Agora se você quiser fazer isso via código, seria algo parecido com isso:

```
const checkPortInUse = async (port) => { ... };
const killProcessUsingPort = async (port) => { ... };

if (await checkPortInUse(PORTA)) {
   await killProcessUsingPort(PORTA);
} else {
   server.listen(PORTA, ()...);
}
```

Para implementação dos métodos citados, seguem referências:

- verificar se uma porta está em uso: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29872303/568329
- descobrir o PID do processo utilizando uma porta: https://www.npmjs.com/package/port-pid
- matar processo com nodeJS: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/process.html#processkillpid-signal

Answer (score -3):

Para fechar uma conexão em um servidor HTTP, você pode chamar o método 'server.close()'. Esse método irá encerrar a conexão e interromper a escuta de novas conexões na porta especificada.

Aqui está um exemplo de como você poderia utilizar esse método para fechar uma conexão e abrir uma nova:

```
if (server.isConnected) {
  server.close(() => {
    console.log('Conexão fechada');
    server.listen(PORTA, () => {
      console.log(`Servidor escutando na porta ${PORTA}`);
    });
  });
} else {
  server.listen(PORTA, () => {
    console.log(`Servidor escutando na porta ${PORTA}`);
  });
}
```

Note que o método 'server.close()' é assíncrono e aceita uma função de callback que será chamada quando a conexão for fechada. Isso significa que, para abrir uma nova conexão depois de fechar a anterior, você deve esperar até que a conexão seja fechada e, então, chamar o método server.listen() para iniciar a escuta de novas conexões.

Comment: Mas não tem como eu fechar a conexão pelo Gerenciador de Tarefas, tipo pegar o processo em que o meu servidor está executando e finalizar a tarefa??

Comment: o usuário já não estava fazendo isso? usando o método `.close()` eu não entendi o que sugeriu, se ele já estava utilizando o método `close()`.